# Problem with AWS ECR docker login on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I use this command to get AWS ECR login token

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-southeast-1
```

After that i run docker login using the output from aws command

```
sudo docker login -u AWS -p eyJwYX****** https://****8010.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

But the result is

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-pass": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``
```

I really don't have any idea how to fix this error i try search everywhere but still no luck

Comment: why you are trying to log in by this way? while you just need to execute token that return by AWS and you can do push pull what ever with ECS in that session

Comment: I already try that, but when i try to push, it shows error 
`no basic auth credentials`

Comment: before pushing run aws configure and set your secret key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following steps to fix your docker-credential-pass:

1. Install docker-credential-pass

   ```
   wget https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/v0.6.0/docker-credential-pass-v0.6.0-amd64.tar.gz 
   tar -xf docker-credential-pass-v0.6.0-amd64.tar.gz
   chmod +x docker-credential-pass
   sudo mv docker-credential-pass /usr/local/bin/
   ```
2. Setup pass and gpg

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y pass gpg
   gpg2 --gen-key
   pass init "<PASTE THE GPG-ID>"
   pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check
   (Set it as "pass")
   pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check
   docker-credential-pass list
   (You should not see "pass store is uninitialized")
   ```
3. Add the credsStore line to your ~/.docker/config.json

   ```
   {
       "auths": {
           **SKIPPED**
       },
       "credsStore": "pass"
   }
   ```

   Then you should be able to login.

Comment: Not working it still show some error
`Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: 'pass store is uninitialized'`

Comment: Ok so now we made progress, docker-credential-pass is installed properly. But the pass store is not configured properly let. I updated the steps, can you try again?

Comment: In my case, step gpg2 --gen-key was hanging. Had to follow the following steps (as found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/471412/gpg-gen-key-hangs-at-gaining-enough-entropy-on-centos-6) to get out of it:

Open a ssh session

sudo apt-get install rng-tools

In another SSH window open

gpg --gen--key

Go back to your first SSH session and run

sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom

Let this run till gpg generates your keys!

Then you can kill rngd

sudo kill -9 $(pidof rngd)